# Floating image at top corner of page

Tags: html, css

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnZYB.png)
if you click on this link you will see at left corner of the navigation bar i want to create an folat image like it 
so i started to get some codes to preform it 
so i found this

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div class="menu">
         <li>
           <img style="float: left;margin-left: -50%;" src="../images/logo.png" alt="Tera Host inc." height="60" width="200">
          </li>
       </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

but its appearing at the top of the page i want something on the top left corner so an friend told me to do something 
You have to make 2 divs following each other
And on each one you do style="float:left;"
And when yuu re done with the floating left
Make a big div that contain those divs
and on the ending do

so if anyone could help me pls reply the whole code
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML is invalid for a start, `li` must be contained in a `ul` or `ol`. If you *cant really write codes* this is not really the site for you as, and I quote form the first pararaph or the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The answers you will get are likely to be technical in nature. This is not a site to write code for you. Try some beginning [HTML and CSS Tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML).

Comment: Hello i am new in this things so pls go easy with me  + i am trying to learn

Comment: I have no issue with being new and trying to learn. I just wanted to set your expectations with what you may experiecne from StackOverflow. It is a great resource for getting for geting answers for a coding problem you may be having, but it is not really a great "Learning resource" for that you would want tutorials and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear with your question! But i just gave a try in an assumption and I think you need to make the menu & logo float separately.

You can check this fiddle, 
**https://jsfiddle.net/8brvykvn/1/**

```
<div class="header">
<a href="#" class="logo">
<img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Tera Host inc." height="60" width="200"></a>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Game Monitor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TS3 Admin</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.header a{
  float: left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.header .menu{
  float : left;
  margin : 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear: both
}

.header .menu li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
}

.header .menu li > a{
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: i cant really write codes so could you write for me the ffloat separately code?